# No funciona .forEach en javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Cuando intento recorrer un array que esta dentro de un objeto json y me devuelve undefined:

primero hago un require del json:

```
const commands = require("./commands.json");
```

Luego lo uso con el foreach:

```
commands.utilidad.forEach((command) => {
  return command;
})
```

y este es el json:

```
{
"diversion": ["comandos..."],
"moderacion": ["comandos..."],
"utilidad": ["comandos..."]
}
```

Comment: ¿De dónde sale la propiedad utilidad?

Comment: que te rentorna un console.log de comandos?

Comment: esto me devuelve el console log:


`
{ moderacion: [ 'bs!kick', 'bs!ban', 'bs!mute' ],
  utilidad: 
   [ 'bs!info',
     'bs!serverinfo',
     'bs!channelinfo',
     'bs!status',
     'bs!ping',
     'bs!filehelp' ],
  diversion: [ 'bs!futuro', 'bs!say', 'bs!avatar', 'bs!cat(en desarollo)' ] }
`

Comment: la propiedad utilidad sale del objeto json

Comment: forEach no retorna nada, debes hacer algo en la funcion, console.log(command) etc

Answer (score 1):

Primera observación: **Objeto !== JSON**. JSON es un formato de texto. Objeto no es texto.

Segunda observación:

Estás haciendo un `return` dentro del `forEach()` que por defecto devuelve `undefined`.

Si tu archivo `comandos.json` contiene los datos que dices, todo irá bien. Mira lo que sucede:

```js
const commands = {
  diversion: ['saltar', 'correr', 'nadar'],
  moderacion: ['revisar', 'corregir', 'votar'],
  utilidad: ['cargar', 'guardar', 'borrar' ]
}

// aqui muestra los comandos
commands.utilidad.forEach(command => {
  console.log(command);
});

// aqui devuelve 'undefined' y no muestra nada.
commands.utilidad.forEach(command => {
  return command;
});
```

Si lo que deseas es guardar los valores de `utilidad`, puedes sacarlos directamente dentro de una variable:

```
let utilidad = command.utilidad; // <- crea una array que contiene los elementos
```

Si vas a realizar operaciones con los elementos 1 a 1 y devolverlos ya evaluados, te sugiero usar [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map).